# Rotate Android video for display on web

Tags: android, firefox, video, ffmpeg, portrait

I'm building a website.  I'm trying to load my first video onto it.  This mp4 video is in portrait orientation and was recorded on an Android device.

When I load this mp4 onto my website, it plays perfectly (in portrait orientation) on Chrome; however, it plays in landscape orientation on Firefox & IE.  I realise that this is because Chrome is using the rotation metadata that is stored within the mp4 to play the video in the correct orientation, while FF & IE don't use this metadata.

I've tried to correct this issue using FFMPEG, and various combinations of the Transpose, Metadata & Rotate commands.  I am using MediaInfo to view the metadata associated with the files that I produce using FFMPEG.

My problem is:
1) If I use Transpose=1, then on FF & IE & Windows Media Player, the resulting video is actually rotated through 180 degrees, and the metadata shows the file width and depth to be the same as the original file.
2) If I use -metadata:s:v rotate=0 (I've also tried rotate=90), then MediaInfo tells me that the resulting files width & depth are now portrait, but FF & IE & WMP will not play the resulting file.  WMP plays the sound but no image, and FF gives an error message "Error Loading This Resource".

What ffmpeg command do I need to use to convert a portrait MP4 recorded an android device into an mp4 that will play in the correct orientation on Firefox?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will have to re-encode it to "physically" rotate the video if you want the browsers or players that do not respect the rotation metadata to play it using the proper orientation.

A modern version of `ffmpeg` will automatically rotate the video according to the rotation metadata (and will avoid copying the input rotation metadata to the output), so just run:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Brilliant - your solution worked first time. https://www.aboutdogs.co.nz/why-is-video-so-hard/      Tried to up vote your answer, but I don't yet have the required reputation :-(